# How do I remove the sink drain in this situation?

Tags: plumbing, sink, drain

I am replacing the faucets/drain in one of my bathrooms. I am trying to remove the drain, but I'm having a lot of trouble. I think it might be soldered on, but I'm not sure why it would be. What's the easiest method for removing the drain?

[image: http://beckman.co/images/sink1.jpg] 
(below sink)

[image] 
(above sink)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a diagram of the drain:

[image]

It looks to me like you've unscrewed the nut, but not the flange (which is a separate piece that screws to the inside of the tailpiece, while the nut screws to the outside of the tailpiece).

If things are not loosening easily, you can try some penetrating oil or WD-40 and letting it sit for a while, it may help if there is any rust or corrosion on the threads. The place this would cause a problem if anywhere would be on the outside at the top of the tailpipe.

Comment: Thanks. It was the flange. I was trying to get the nut & washer off from below the basin, but that was the wrong way to do it. The flange was REALLY stuck and WD-40 didn't help. I ended up brute forcing the flange with the backside of a hammer (in an attempt to loosen/tear up the rim), and while doing so it eventually broke the hold on the pipe. Not the right/clean way to do it, but I was able to do so without damaging the sink, so it works for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a clarifying answer, only because I got stuck on this for a while. The diagram for the checked answer was super helpful, but the flange on my drain (which I think is exactly the same design as the original poster) was much shorter than I expected (see photo below) and screwed to the *outside* of the tailpiece.  I got it off by lifting the flange+tailpiece up from below the sink, and then sliding channel lock pliers below the flange.

Hope that's helpful to someone...

[image: flange]

Answer (score 0):

The WD-40/3 in 1 oil failed to loosen the flange. It continued to spin despite attempting to hold it with pliers as I turned the nut counterclockwise.  I eventually hacksawed the tailpipe and the flange was easily removed.